# How can I ignore images and other unnecessary files to lower response time in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have been fetching html documents with Jsoup like this:

`Jsoup.connect(url).get();`

But I have noticed that Jsoup waits for everything to load before giving me the data.
I know that the data I'm looking for is in the Html document. when looking at a response (through google Chrome Network analysis tool) that the html document is sent the first ~100ms  and I don't want to wait an extra ~1500ms to get access to that data.

Is there a way to make the request skip the unneeded files or stop the request after Revinge the html document?

any recommendations that could make the process of fetching the data a bit faster would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is actually wrong. Jsoup only fetches the one document you pass the url to. It does not fetch any resources (images, css, js files, etc.) automatically. You can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/fb588770a45a9ab6b64fce0f800d50ec225a42ee/src/main/java/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.java#L710) to prove that. Jsoup will only follow redirects, if activated.

Maybe the server delays the response, because you send a request without a `User-Agent` header. You can solve this using `Connection.userAgent()` and add e.g. the chrome user agent:

```
Jsoup.connect(url)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36")
        .get();
```

Comment: but that does not explain why the Jsoup get() runs for as long as it would take for Chrome to load the page. Jsoup in this case should be almost  as fast as wget but it is a whole second slower than wget.

Comment: It is quite hard to guess, without knowing the url you are talking about. Have you tried using an user agent? Many servers delay the requests which don't have an user agent. So maybe it is not an jsoup problem...

Comment: I have tried to use a useragent but it does not shorten my times. The url is https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/beefrendang_78767

Comment: I have tried on 15 other urls too and they all have the same problem with delays.
The page that i reference when talking about time is https://koket.se/wrap-fylld-med-omelett-avokado-sriracha-och-majonnas

BBC takes 1.8 sec on the computer and 8.4 sec on a phone

Comment: I just found the real problem. even though jsoup takes 1.6 seconds to fetch it takes about 2-7 sec to convert it with HtmlCleaner and XpathFactory. mb. my question is irreverent because I didnt give the whole context. Sorry